# Why does SharePoint Workflow Project in VS 2008 get modified every time it's opened?

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

The same goes for the workflow source files -- every time I open the project or go to the source file, it's indicating (by the asterisk) that the file has been modified. Which means two things:

- when closing VS, I always get the "Project has been changed, do you want to save changes?" prompt. It's annoying but I can live with that.
- More importantly though, I cannot debug the workflow because when the debugger is attached, I get the "Cannot modify the file while debugger's running" error prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I showed a video of this to a Program Manager on the Visual Studio tools team - he agreed it was a bug. Apparently there are no plans to fix it for VS2008, but they checked at the time and apparently it doesn't happen in SP2010/VS2010. Haven't verified this though.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same.

Don't know why it's happening, but I have heard people saying it's a bug.